# Button on TitleBar simply doesn't display Sencha Touch

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Here is my code.

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Sencha',
    launch: function() {

        Ext.create("Ext.TabPanel", {
            fullscreen: true,
            tabBarPosition: 'bottom',

            items: [
            {
                xtype: 'titlebar',
                docked: 'top',
                title: 'MyApp',
                itmes: [{
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'Add',
                    align: 'right'
                }]
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

Someone said to use Navigation View, and I saw examples using Ext.Viewport.add(), but I don't like either of them. I just wonder is it possible to add buttons on titlebar and bind events onto those buttons in configuration directly?

Update:

I found the approach--> using Ext.Viewport.add() , only works in desktop browers, but doesn't work when generated to cordova project and/or deployed onto devices (both Android and Windows Phone 8), the TitleBar simply doesn't display at all.

It makes me more urgent to find the way how to write the titlebar, button and its events into configuration.

Comment: Why are you adding a `titlebar` in a `TabPanel`, when there is already a `tabbar` ?

Comment: hi @Saffron I think you feel confused about the uses of titlebar and tabBar. They have different usages. In my case, I need tabBar to flip to different pages, whereas TitleBar is used only on the first page to give extra information.

Comment: Ok, your code sample does not really reflect that, as you create one tab per items in a TabPanel.
Is the typo on 'items' intentional ? itmes: [{

Comment: hi @Saffron, the code only creates one tabBar on the TabPanel, not one tab per items under a TabPanel. Yes, it's a typo(how blind I was >_<). I corrected and now everything works like a charm. You made my day mate :) Please post your review and I'd like to choose it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a typo :   `itmes` should be items :)